# Use Git to synchronize one project from a "Repo" repository

Tags: git, git-repo

Some people in my company use [Repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) to manage multiple repositories. I need to read (not alter/commit) some of this content.

I'm hoping to avoid installing Repo, and just use Git. Here are the instructions provided for getting the repository I care about:

```
repo init -u git://git-master/x/manifest.git -b dev/foo-bar -m bar.xml
repo sync
```

**How can I use vanilla Git to synchronize this same information?**

Answer (score 3):

[git-repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) use a file called `manifest.xml` to list all the git repositories of your project.

To get access to the repository using `git` only, you just have to get the `manifest.xml`, read the repository URL, and clone it.

---

## First: Get the manifest

```
$ git clone -b dev/foo-bar git://git-master/x/manifest.git
$ vi manifest/bar.xml
```

---

## Second: Read the repository URL

You should have something like this (check the [manifest format](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>

  <remote  name="origin" fetch="git://git-master/x" />

  <default revision="master" remote="origin" />

  <project name="my/first/project" />
  <project name="my/second/project" />

</manifest>
```

Search the repository you want to clone (e.g `my/second/project`), build the clone URL from the `manifest.remote.fetch` property. Here we have:

```
clone URL = git://git-master/x/my/second/project
```

*NOTE: The `manifest.remote.fetch` can be an absolute or a relative URL. If it is a relative, you have to add the manifest URL before.*

---

## Third: Clone the repository

```
git clone git://git-master/x/my/second/project
```

*NOTE: You can check the `manifest.default.revision` and the `manifest.project.revision` to be sure that you have fetch the good branch.*

---

Nevertheless, as `repo` is just a script you can easily install it in your home directory, like this:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Comment: How to do this with eGIT eclipse plugin? Any idea